# Given a fixed cel width, can I change the fontsize so that the text will fit inside the cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that will automatically adjust the height of a cell, so that text will fit inside that cell.
However now I want to change the fontsize of the text inside the cell, so that the font will shrink and grow to make the text fit inside the cell, so I don't have to make the cell width a fixed size.

How do I do this in VBA?

I need to know the width of text, given a font size

Option 1.

```
TextWidth = WidthOfAText(Range("A1").Value)
FontAdjustmentFactor = Range("A1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth / TextWidth
FontSize = Range("A1").Font.Size * FontAdjustmentFactor
Range("A1").Font.Size = Max(4, Min(10, FontSize))
```

or I need to know whether the text will fix and do some sort of trial and error routine.

Option 2.

```
Range("A1").Font.Size = 10
While (Text_does_not_fit AND Range("A1").Font.Size >= 5) 
  Range("A1").Font.Size = Range("A1").Font.Size - 1
Wend
```

How do I do this? (Preferably using code like in option 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non programatically just right click on the cell -> Format Cells -> Alignment -> Shrink to Fit

Code wise is:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").ShrinkToFit = True
```

Comment: Let me know if that's not what you're looking for, I'll see what else I can come up with.

Comment: Accepted, this is exactly what I need. I still need to make sure the fontsize does not get too small, but I can do that using an event, assuming the fontsize persists after I turn off the `shrinktofit`.

Comment: (...it doesn't.)